# Unable to get full refresh rate on my monitor

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I’m using MacBook Pro 13.3inch M2chip and just purchased new prism plus x340 pro monitor. I was using urgreen converter to connect my monitor and MacBook but only can get up to 50hz refresh rate.

Any solutions for this? I wish I can unlock full performance on my monitor with my MacBook pro. Your suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the following are the outlined specifications for your Mac. The specifications clarify that the maximum refresh rate supported on external monitors is up to 60Hz.

The most likely reason you're getting 50Hz at the moment is because of your Ugreen Adapter. You may be better off going for a more suitable dock that can connect reliably with your Thunderbolt 3 Type C Ports. The original Apple ones are better suited for the design of those Type C ports. Third party adapters and docks are not always made to the actual design specifications for Apple devices even though they might be compatible.

The Type-C Ports on Apple Devices have a small cut internally which have a locking mechanism and their products are designed to lock in correctly. Third party products are not usually designed with that consideration in mind, which may eventually cause other issues with the device.

> Display Support Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the
> built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> One external display with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz Thunderbolt 3
> digital video output
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C VGA, HDMI, DVI, and Thunderbolt 2
> output supported using adapters (sold separately)

Comment: Meaning if I purchase Apple Original dock might be able to unlock 100hz on my monitor with my MacBook pro?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It will be limited to 60Hz because that is the limitation from the MacBook Pro. There isn't another way around it sadly.